# matplotlib colorbar tick label outside bug

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

When custom ticks are outside vmin or vmax, custom labels are shifted :

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import random

# Make plot with horizontal colorbar
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = random((250,250)) + 3.5

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=2.5,vmax=4.5)

cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.afmhot, norm=norm)
ax.set_title('Gaussian noise with horizontal colorbar')

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[1,2,3,4], orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_ticklabels(['one','two', 'three', 'four'])# horizontal colorbar

plt.savefig("example.png")
```

[image]

[image]

Is it a bug? Any workaround?

Comment: just for me to fully understand: You want to be able to specify ticks independent (and some of them possibly outside) of the data range. You then want to assign custom labels. When plotted, matplotlib should know that - in this case - the first two ticks are outside the range (and not plotted) and therefor only utilize the third and fourth custom label?

Comment: Exactly. I also wrote an issue on github.

Comment: This is the correct behavior for `FixedFormatter` which is what is being used when you use `set_ticklabels`

Comment: You should set the ticks themselves as well to control where the labels appear...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first actual tick and compare the label to values/locations of the ticks you specified. Then, you can use that index to start your custom labels.
Here's a modified example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import random

# Make plot with horizontal colorbar
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = random((250,250)) + 3.5

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=2.5,vmax=4.5)

cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.afmhot, norm=norm)
ax.set_title('Gaussian noise with horizontal colorbar')

TICKS = [1,2,3,4]

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=TICKS, orientation='horizontal')

# the following command extracts the first tick object from the x-axis of
# the colorbar:
tick = cbar.ax.get_xaxis().get_major_ticks()[0]

# Here you compare the text of the first tick label to all the tick locations
# you have defined in TICKS (they need to be strings for this):
CUSTOM_INDEX = [str(S) for S in TICKS].index(tick.label1.get_text())

TICKLABELS = ['one','two', 'three', 'four']

# Now, you can use the index of the actual first tick as a starting tick to
# your list of custom labels:
cbar.set_ticklabels(TICKLABELS[CUSTOM_INDEX:])# horizontal colorbar

plt.show()
```

[image: new custom labels]

Answer (score 1):

This is not something specific to `colorbar`. If you specify the tick labels as a list of strings, they are always (also on X or Y axes) allocated to the first ticks. See this trivial example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([0,1],[1,0])
ax.set_xticklabels(["one", "two", "three"])
```

This draws:

[image]

Now the tick labels `one`, `two` and `three` correspond to 0.0, 0.2, and 0.4, respectively.

If we zoom this in by:

```
ax.set_xlim(.1,.9)
```

We get:

[image]

Now the same labels corespond to 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 as they are the leftmost labels.

So, the label strings are not bound to the tick positions.

There are workarounds, but the best one really depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: 'workarounds' is the wrong phrase, mpl is doing exactly what it is being told to do.  However, you should never use a `FixedFormatter` without also using a `FixedLocator` as other wise your data gets de-coupled from your labels.